# Serving merged PDF to the browser using CAM::PDF library

Tags: perl, cgi-bin, cam-pdf

EDIT:

I changed my question again:

I am using [this](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/lib/CAM/PDF.pm) library to manipulate PDF files.

I am using this code to serve the output to the browser:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use lib "..\\mymodules\\CAM-PDF-1.57\\lib";

use CAM::PDF;
my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new('doc1.pdf');

# append the other file
my $anotherpdf = CAM::PDF->new('doc2.pdf');

$pdf->appendPDF($anotherpdf);

print "Content-Type: application/pdf\n";
print "Content-Disposition: inline\n\n";

print "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n";
print "Accept-Ranges: bytes\n\n";

$pdf->output();
```

The result:

I get only the first pdf file loaded in the browser.

Problem solved:

I had to add `$pdf->clean();` before the `$pdf->output();` command, and it works perfect. :)

Answer (score 0):

You said there is no TEMP variable, but your code using it:

```
$pdf->cleanoutput($ENV{"TEMP"} . '\\out1.pdf');
```

Try to set it to some value (I assuming that you are using windows)

```
$ENV{'TEMP'}='c:\tmp';
mkdir($ENV{'TEMP'});
die "$ENV{'TEMP'} not exists" if ! -d $ENV{'TEMP'};
$pdf->cleanoutput($ENV{"TEMP"} . '\\out1.pdf');
```

Why are you using // in some path? Like: use lib "..\mymodules\CAM-PDF-1.57\lib"; In use lib statement always use full path.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. This code is supposed to run from a CD, and the requirement is to not write to the local computer. So, I want to find a way to use %TEMP% folder of windows, or another solutions. I cannot decide to create a folder myself. Thank you